# Efeito 100% por cima do Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Estou precisando colocar um efeito overlay por cima de um Carousel do bootstrap, mas que pegue toda altura do mesmo.

Esclarecendo melhor ... a primeira vez que trabalhei nesse estilo - não nesse trecho que enviei - através de algumas modificações eu até consegui fazer com que o efeito ficasse 100% sobre o Carousel e acompanhasse dessa forma perfeitamente em qualquer dispositivo, só que no IE eu tive um problema, pois meu menu foi totalmente jogado para fora do slider (para o lado direito do monitor onde não tinha mais nada para visualizar além dele próprio), enquanto que nos outros navegadores funcionou super bem.
Por isso decidi refazer tudo - no caso foi esse trecho que lhes mostrei - ao qual ajustei o menu e deixei pendente a parte do efeito, só que agora estou com essa grande dúvida de como resolver  :-(

```css
.efeito-overlay {
  z-index: 100;
}

nav {
  z-index: 200;
}

.slide {
  z-index: 40;
}

.efeito-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px), repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px), linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), url();
  background-position: bottom, left, top left, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.floated {
  float: left;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav #menu {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 1px !important;
  float: right;
}

nav .icon-bar {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <header>


    <div class="efeito-overlay"></div>
    <div class="slide clearfix">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item slide1 active floated"><img src="imagens/1-slide.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item floated"><img src="imagens/2-slide.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item floated"><img src="imagens/3-slide.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mymenu">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
         </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="index.html">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="mymenu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vc quer cobrir a página toda ou apenas a parte do Carousel?

Comment: Apenas a parte do carousel

Comment: Por que não coloca a div overlay dentro da div do Carousel?

Comment: Olá dvd, eu tentei fazer isso mas não funcionou pra mim.  Obrigada!

Comment: Então vc vai ter que fazer isso com JavaScript, porque a div overlay está fora do Carousel e fica sem referência.

Comment: Olá dvd, editei minha pergunta e expliquei um pouco melhor essa questão.

Comment: Fernanda eu deixei um comentário na minha resposta, olha se resolve, se não der certo vou pedir pra vc Editar sua pergunta com tudo que vc tem de código ai, pq não consegui simular esse erro aqui, do jeito que fiz o Overlay funcionou direitinho no meu teste

Answer (score 1):

Na mexi praticamente em nada no seu CSS, só coloquei um `height` definido para o `.slider` e `overflow:hidden` para as imagens não ficarem extrapolando a altura do *slider*.

Outra coisa que foi preciso fazer é colocar a `div` `overlay` dentro do *slider*, assim ela vai acompanhar a altura do `.slider`, independente da altura que ele tiver.

Seu slider também tinha alguns problemas na organização das tag, inclusive a classe `floated` na imagem, que impede que ela ocupe 100% da largura do slider.

Aqui tem a documentação oficial do Slider do Bootstrap3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel

Agora veja o exemplo de como ficou o resultado com o overlay sob o slider. *(pode ser que vc tenha que fazer uns ajustes na sua **nav** caso queira ela por cima do slider)*

```css
.efeito-overlay {z-index: 100;}
nav{ z-index: 200; }
.slide{ z-index: 40;}

.efeito-overlay {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100% !important;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;

 background-image: 
 repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px),
 repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px),
 linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), url();

 background-position: bottom, left, top left, center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
  
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
} 
.slide{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 200px; /* aqui vc define a altura do slider */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden; /* isso evita que a imagem ultrapasse altura do slider */
}
.carousel-inner img{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.floated {
  float: left;
}
  
header{
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
}
nav{
 width: 100%;
 height: 130px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 padding: 10px 100px;
 display: flex;
 align-content: center;
 display: inline-block;
}
nav #menu{
 background-color: #CCC;
 border-radius: 1px !important;
 float: right;
}

nav .icon-bar{
 background-color: #FFF;
}
nav a{
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.875em;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<header>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide clearfix" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="efeito-overlay"></div>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/354/300" alt="Los Angeles">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/355/300" alt="Chicago">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/356/300" alt="New york">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mymenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>    
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="index.html">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="mymenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">           
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
      

</header>
```

---

## EDIT

O problema que vc relatou no comentário ocorre porque a imagem vai seguer a proporção dela (altura X largura). Quando vc reduz muito a largura da tela e imagem fica com a proporção Altura/Largura alterada já que ela tem 100% de width e altura "automática.

Para resolver o seu problema vc pode por `min-height: 500px !important;` em alguns lugares do CSS, porém a imagem vai ficar "achatada" na horizontal, pq vc vai restringir a altura, mas a largura fica sempre 100%...

Execute o *Snippet* e faça os teste de largura de tela que vc via entender melhor. A solução para não deixar achatar é usar os `@media` para tratar a imagem para cada largura de tela sem deixar ela deformar demais as proporções *largura/altura*

Segue código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    .efeito-overlay {z-index: 100;}
nav{ z-index: 200; }
.slide{ z-index: 40;}

.efeito-overlay {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100% !important;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;

 background-image: 
 repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px),
 repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px),
 linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), url();

 background-position: bottom, left, top left, center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
.slide{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px; /* aqui vc define a altura do slider */
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden; /* isso evita que a imagem ultrapasse altura do slider */
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
 width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 500px !important;
} 
.carousel-inner {
    min-height: 500px !important;
    width: 100%;
} 
.carousel-inner img{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 500px !important;
}
.carousel-inner .active {
    min-height: 500px !important;
    width: 100%;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.floated {
  float: left;
}
  
header{
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
}
nav{
 width: 100%;
 height: 130px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 padding: 10px 100px;
 display: flex;
 align-content: center;
 display: inline-block;
}
nav #menu{
 background-color: #CCC;
 border-radius: 1px !important;
 float: right;
}

nav .icon-bar{
 background-color: #FFF;
}
nav a{
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.875em;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <header>

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide clearfix" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="efeito-overlay"></div>
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/354/300" class="img-fluid" alt="Los Angeles">
              <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/355/300" class="img-fluid" alt="Chicago">
              <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
          
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/356/300" class="img-fluid" alt="New york">
              <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <nav class="navbar">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mymenu">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
              </button>    
              <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="index.html">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="mymenu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">           
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
              
        
        </header>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá ... com sua adaptação nem precisei mexer no menu pois continuou funcionando bem, porém em resoluções menores o height que você acrescentou acaba acompanhando a tela.  Só eu estou vendo assim ou pra você também aparece?

Comment: Fernanda o height deve ser sempre 200px que foi a altura que eu usei no exemplo. Se essa altura está variando certifique-se se tem essa tag na `<head>` da sua página `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. Se vc estiver testando essa **responsividade** direto aqui no *snippet* do StackOverflow não vai dar certo mesmo não, vc tem que colocar o código no seu projeto. Qualquer coisa é só falar

Comment: Oi Hugo, então eu copiei sim seu código em um novo arquivo para fazer o teste e no caso eu precisava de um height maior, então o aumentei, sendo que apesar da imagem manter o responsivo, a div slide e o overlay não acompanham 100% a imagem.  Foi isso que me referia se também aconteceu com você.

Comment: Veja pela imagem:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/screen1-png-e5646ebc-9c21-4175-8ce4-68d74ee7ab9f

Comment: @Fernanda vc colocou o `overflow:hidden` na div com id="myCarousel"? Se vc já tiver colocado acho que o problema deve ser outro CSS que está interferindo ali de alguma forma.... Eu fiz alguns testes aqui e não consegui simular esse erro, o meu não deixa o overlay escapar do Slider! Confere o override, se não resolver atualize vou pedir para vc Editar a sua pergunta com o código COMPLETO que vc está usando no momento

Comment: Oi Hugo, eu copiei seu código exatamente como me enviou e a única modificação que fiz foi aumentar o height da classe .slider de 200px para 500px e mais nada.  Vou hoje ainda dar uma analisada com mais calma e qualquer coisa te retorno.  Fico grata !!

Comment: @Fernanda fiz uma Edição na minha resposta, da uma olhada no detalhes ai do seu problema

Answer (score 0):

A posição da tua div "efeito-overlay" está errada. Você está colocando ela fora do teu slide, se você quer que ela pegue 100% da altura do slide, ela tem que estar dentro da div do slide, para que possa pegar a propriedade height do elemento pai. No teu código, a tua "efeito-overlay" está pegando o height do header.

Comment: Insira um código exemplo para ilustrar melhor a sua resposta.

Comment: Obrigada Bianca, sim, eu sei que minha classe .efeito-overlay está acompanhando o height do meu header, mas eu tentei fazer modificações nas posições e não tive sucesso, por isso pedi ajuda aqui no forum.  Te agradeço de qualquer forma e vou depois fazer novos testes.

Answer (score 0):

Mude o .slide para `position: relative` e utilize `.slide:after` com todo seu css do `.efeito-overlay` e remova a div do html assim:

```
.slide:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;

    background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 4px),
    linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), url();

    background-position: bottom, left, top left, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px; /* aqui vc define a altura do slider */
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden; /* isso evita que a imagem ultrapasse altura do slider */
}
```